# How to include a database's views in the SQL Reporting Services Model

Tags: sql, reporting-services, view, reporting, sql-view

I am new to SQL Reporting Services. I need to create a report from a SQL view in my database. When I add the database as a data source and generate a model from that data source, the model includes the database's tables, but not its views.

Is there a way to include the views in the model so I can use them in my report?

**Additional Details:** Using SQL Server and Reporting Services 2005

Comment: have you checked permissions on the views?

Comment: what version of reporting services and SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Good idea. I checked it out and permissions are not the cause of the issue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: SQL Server and Reporting Services 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend pointed out that the problem here is that a model is not necessary for what I want to do. The reason I thought it was necessary is because Report Builder 1.0 requires you to select a model when you create the report. Business Intelligence Development Studio, however, does not (Neither do Report Builder versions 2+).

I will be making the report in Business Intelligence Development Studio instead.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345300%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

This is a useful link to create a model via Business Intelligence Studio (which can include views too).